# Rare events ratios

Tags: estimation, importance-sampling, rare-events

Suppose I can sample from some probability measure $P$ and the event $A$ has a very low probability: $P(A)\ll 1$. I know that it is hard to estimate $P(A)$ and I need to resort to importance sampling, however here I am interested in a different problem. Let's say $A = A_1\cup A_2$ both of positive $P$-probability  and I would like to know $P(A_1)/P(A)$. Is that easier to estimate?

Comment: In what form is the probability measure specified? This will determine what is "easy" to do and what is not. For instance, let $X,Y$ be independent standard normal variables and $A_1: X^4+Y^4\ge 2500,$ $A_2: X^2Y^2\ge 625.$  This is almost impossible to do with brute-force sampling from the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, since $\Pr(A)\lt 10^{-11}$, but--because that distribution can be manipulated analytically--it is easy to compute the ratio (which is $0.591\ldots$) numerically or even with clever Monte-Carlo simulation. Would such methods be accessible in your circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

A precise answer would depend on an exact definition of "easier" and whether accuracy is determined by ratio or absolute difference. To illustrate:

Suppose $A_1$ is 1 in 1,000,000 and $A_2$ is also rare, say 1 in 500,000.  When I tried to do this in `R` I got errors about lengths of vectors. But with 1 in 1,000 and 1 in 500 we can do it.

```
set.seed(1010381)
x1 <- runif(100000, 0, 1) < 0.001
sum(x1)/length(x1)
x2 <- runif(100000, 0, 1) < 0.002
sum(x2)/length(x2)
sum(x1)/sum(x2)
```

I didn't do a bunch of runs, but in 5 runs:

$P(X_1) = .00101, .00087, .00098, .00183, .0011$

$P(X_2) =  .00167, .00207, 0.0018, .00231, .00204$

$P(\frac{X_1}{X_2}) = .6047, .42069, .5384, .4892, .5392$

So, in absolute terms, all the estimates of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are close, but the ratio of largest to smallest is 2.1 for $X_1$, 1.38 for $X_2$ and 1.44 for the ratio. I believe that the set for $X_2$ is "lucky".

Comment: I believe the point of the question is that this brute-force approach for truly rare events may be impossible to carry out because the events might never be seen in such simulations.